# Onchange event with adobe air and javascript

Tags: javascript, air, adobe

I'm developing an application with adobe air and javascript. I have a select element where I added an onchange event . Every time the select change value the application make a ajax call to fetch data to populate another field. But I can not get any response from the server. Simply nothing happens. Anyone know any limitations to the event and how to overcome it?

```
select_object.addEventListener("change",callServer,false);

function callServer(event){

            var a= event.currentTarget.value;

            var variables = new air.URLVariables("value=" + a);

            var u ="http://www.exemple.com";


            var request = new air.URLRequest(u);
            request.data = variables;
            request.method = air.URLRequestMethod.POST;         

            loader = new air.URLLoader();
            loader.dataFormat = air.URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
            loader.addEventListener(air.Event.COMPLETE, comp);
            loader.addEventListener(air.Event.SECURITY_ERROR, function(event){alert('error');});

            try {
            loader.load(request);
        } catch (error) {
            alert("Unable to load URL");
        }


        function comp(e) {
             alert('sucess')
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the event listener called?you can add an alert/trace call in the handler start to check. Also you are missing a event handler for IO_ERROR in the loader.
Do you forgot to call loader.load() ?

Also add a handler for IO_ERROR

```
loader.addEventListener(air.Event.IO_ERROR, function(event){alert('error');});
```

Comment: Yes, the event listener is called and i tried all possible response events, but doesn't output any messages

Comment: @ManuelGerardoPereira did you forgot loader.load()  ?

Comment: sorry I forgot to copy that lines, but they are in the original code, so I don't forgot. It is very strange issue.

Comment: @ManuelGerardoPereira I stil not see a handler for IO_ERROR ,check my edit and also check the UrlLoader  documentation and add all handlers for all events if needed(for status and progress) and let us know what you get

Comment: I set all type of events on the urlLoader object. The code dispatch the urlRequest but the events on the urlLoader don't give any output. Any how, I will make it with xmlHttpRequest or with $.ajax().